# JSONP: how to construct ajax query?

Tags: jquery, json, jsonp

I'm trying to work with a JSONP API, across domains. This is an example of the data it returns:

```
photos({"marker":{"@attributes":{"id":"30601","latitude":"52.638061","longitude":"-2.117067","feature":"3","caption":"cat","thumbnailSizes":"60|120|150|180|200|250|300|350|400|400|425|450|500|640"}}});
```

How can I construct an Ajax call that makes use of this data? I keep getting error messages.

This is what I'm trying at the moment:

```
$.ajax({
    url: pm_url,
    data: {},
    type: "get",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function() {
        alert('Sorry, there was a problem getting the photos!');
    }
```

In Firebug, I can see that the data above is being retrieved, but then I see the error message.

What is wrong with the request? (Or the data - though it validates as JSONP.)

UPDATE:

Thanks for the suggestions. I'm now trying:

```
            var photos = function (data) {
              alert(data);
            };
            $.ajax({
                url: pm_url,
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                jsonpCallback: 'photos',
            });
```

This is, weirdly, calling two URLs in Firebug:

```
http://myapi.com/file.jsonp?x=1&y=2?callback=?
http://myapi.com/file.jsonp?x=1&y=2?callback=photos&_=1304982373561
```

The first URL is showing up as an error in the Console. What am I doing wrong?!

It's possible that the API itself is wrong (they're requiring a .jsonp suffix and ignoring the value of callback, which is why the function name is fixed) but I was hoping I could work around it.

Comment: In Firebug/Fiddler what is the response of the request?

Comment: The request itself is 200 OK, returning the data above, but Firebug says: "photos is not a function". Then I see the error message.

Comment: OK, really struggling badly with JSONP. Could anyone help me get this jsFiddle to do something, simply using the Twitter JSONP API? http://jsfiddle.net/R7EPt/8/ thanks!

Comment: This doesn't use JSONP exactly, but it's working.  Hopefully you can take it where you need from here: http://jsfiddle.net/R7EPt/9/

Answer (score 4):

The function-name(photos) is wrong. jQuery will send a GET-parameter named "callback", the value of this parameter is the name the function needs to have.

Response, PHP-example:

```
<?php echo $_GET['callback'].'('.json_encode($some_object).');';?>
```

To explain what happens with jsonp:

assuming a callback-parameter send with value jquery1234:
jQuery will create a temporary function:

```
function jquery1234(data){return data;}
```

So if you send a response like

```
jquery1234({'somevar':'somevalue'});
```

...jQuery will create a script-element of that response, the function gets called and the object will be transferred to the success-function.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way I can force the callback parameter to be called 'photos'? (I don't have control of the API.)

Comment: @simon: Yes, you can add `jsonpCallback:'photos'` to the config. See more info on the [jQuery.ajax API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax)

Answer (score 0):

Why not use $.getJSON() ? http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: Tried that first, also gave me errors. Pretty baffled by JSONP at the moment, I have to say.

Comment: cross domain restrictions - @antonR